# mongooseIM- not able to use mod_vcard_odbc

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I have set up mongooseIM successfully. It wan't to use it with odbc. The module mod_vcard_odbc cannot work properly. When i enter vcard following error occurs-

```
 2014-01-02 19:35:22.192 [error] <0.369.0>@ejabberd_odbc:outer_transaction:400 SQL    transaction restarts exceeded
 ** Restarts: 10
 ** Last abort reason: "#42S22Unknown column 'server' in 'where clause'"
 ** Stacktrace: [{ejabberd_odbc,sql_query_t,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_odbc.erl"},  {line,138}]},{odbc_queries,update_t,4,[{file,"src/odbc_queries.erl"},{line,119}]},{ejabberd_odbc,outer_transaction,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_odbc.erl"},{line,391}]},{ejabberd_odbc,run_sql_cmd,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_odbc.erl"},{line,317}]},{p1_fsm,handle_msg,10,[{file,"src/p1_fsm.erl"},{line,542}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]
** When State == {state,<0.371.0>,mysql,30000,<<"localhost">>,1000,{0,{[],[]}}}
```

I don't know why this error occurs.

Comment: It seems you haven't initialized your SQL database. Look into MONGOOSEIM_REPO/apps/ejabberd/priv/ for a .sql file specific to your database and use it to create the necessary tables.